# Set cookie in Global.asax.cs and get it in the view of asp.net mvc c#

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I registered cookie in session start of Global.asax.cs of asp.net mvc project. And then I want to test the variable of the cookie in the View.

Global.asax.cs :

```
HttpCookie instock = new HttpCookie("instockV");
instock.Value = "1";
Response.Cookies.Add(instock);
```

In my view, I'm using jquery :

```
<div id="test"></div>
$("#test").text($.cookie("instockV"));
```

But the result in my div is `null`.

Anyone know about this issue please share.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know anything about asp.net, but are you sure that the cookie is not HTTP-only?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the plugin of jquery cookie? never the less if you don't have it, to read the cookie the code it's with pure javascript it's easy do it like this

```
function getCookie(c_name) {
    var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
        x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
        x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
        if (x == c_name) {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Tried in you Global.asax the append like this

```
HttpCookie instock = new HttpCookie("instockV");
instock.Value = "1";
Response.AppendCookie(instock);
```

Comment: Jorge, I tried this function, and the value return is `undefined`.

Comment: Well then I recommend that you check the headers response of your browser using the developers tools of chrome, firebug or charles web debugging proxy and see the cookies in the response

Comment: Jorge, Using developer tool of firebug, I didn't see that cookie exist. And I tried to use `Response.AppendCookie(instock);` ready.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24165/discussion-between-socheata-and-jorge)